# Comparing Strings in VB 6.5

Tags: vba, vb6

I am trying to compare two strings in VB but compareTo, compare, equals etc all give compile errors.

```
    If String.Compare(string_one, string_two) = 0 Then
        '...do stuff
    End If
    If String.Equals(string_one, string_two) Then
        '...do stuff
    End If
```

Now both lines give me the error,

> Compile error:
>
> Expected: (

and it highlights the dot after String, i.e.

```
String.(whatever)
______↑__________
```

Do I need to include something, I normally program C, Java and C# so I am not very familiar with VB

Now I am doing this in a very crappy program that uses Microsoft Visual Basic 6.5 is it that these functions just simply do not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB6 just uses the = operator:

```
If string_one = string_two Then
    ''# Do Stuff
End If
```

For that matter you do it that way in VB.Net as well, though vb.net also allows the .Equals() function in this form:

```
If string_one.Equals(string_two) Then
    ''# Do Stuff
End If
```

Comment: wow that makes it easy, I thought I tried that but it always resulted in true.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `StrComp` function:

```
StrComp(String1, String2, [Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare])
```